# Access VBA parameterized query: syntax error in the query clause is incomplete

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

```
 recup = "SELECT id_categorie FROM T_Categorie WHERE T_Categorie.libelle = " & TxtCategId.Value

''retrieve the number of the category which corresponds to the depot

    Set dbcaisse = CurrentDb
    Set rsT = dbcaisse.OpenRecordset(recup, dbOpenDynaset)
    categorie = rsT!id_categorie
      
    ''registration of the deposit
 
 Set dbcaisse = CurrentDb
 Set rsT = dbcaisse.OpenRecordset("T_Mouvement", dbOpenDynaset)
```

when the execution arrives at the level of `Set rsT = dbcaisse.OpenRecordset(recup)` I have this error

thank you for your answers

Comment: That's because `TxtCategId.Value` holds no value.

Comment: For future reference: use Debug.Print. -- [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing your secret value, if present it could be text, thus must be quoted:

```
 recup = "SELECT id_categorie FROM T_Categorie WHERE T_Categorie.libelle = '" & TxtCategId.Value & "'"
```

Comment: your solution works but please what is this story of secret value (I learn in the same time that I code the dev who was in charge of doing it let us down thank you to explain me)

Comment: Only that we (I) had to guess what your finished SQL possibly could be. Had you posted it, the cause of the error message would have been obvious.

Comment: in fact the cause of the message (the error) is the very title of my post, but I also found that by rerunning with your code + debug.print my query where parametrized had the ratings and now it works thanks to you I'll mark as resolved

Answer (score 0):

but when I do a debug.print recup, I have my request with my value,  I have this  `SELECT id_categorie FROM T_Categorie WHERE T_Categorie.libelle = Wester union`